# Document Control

Tags: php, sql, mysql, documentation

**What is the best open source document control app for PHP/MySQL?**

Focus is to be on a system that is robust, easy to use and fast to implement. Needs to have security layers so that files can be public or private. Group assets would be nice. Project management features would be a bonus if they were scalable, robust but not overcomplicated.

EDIT #1:
Just to formalize this question a little more, I would like to ensure you all understand what I mean by Document Control program. We have a lot of files that are associated with multiple projects and multiple customers. I would like document access and document revisions to be managed. When someone is putting a document into the system, the system needs to tag the file and manage its safe data storage. This will also be a collaborative venture in that many people will download and edit each file. Admins would have to be able to control which file is the **CURRENT version** of the file, so that we have the choice of hiding older documents or preventing users from accessing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need version control system.

Try Subversion (SVN) http://subversion.apache.org/. To make it easier you can use TortoiseSVN on windows or RabitVCS on linux.

In subversion you can setup usernames and password for the users and manage groups. It might be a little complex for beginner to setup a fully functional repository with user management...

You can look into [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com/) or other source hosting places.

Comment: Thanks for that response, but Subversion seems geared for computer programming and appears to be heavily layered in jargon. I will definitely try it out though. Thanks for the feedback! (if we go with it I'll +A your answer)

Comment: It is not that bad. It is fairly easy once you understand (couple of hours of playing and you'll be a pro). Especially if you use IDE like Netbeans/Eclipse (based from your question tags), the subversion support is already in place. Look into TortoiseSVN, will make repository experience million times easier. With Tortoise SVN using repository is no harder than FTP with Filezilla or WinSCP.